# Regex to include both decimal and string pattern does not recognize decimal part

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to split both numeric value and string. For instance, 2.25 ft. should be able to split into "2.25" and "ft.". However, the regex below does not recognize .25 but it does recognize 2.

```
var numAlpha = new Regex("(?<Numeric>[0-9 ])*(?<Alpha>[a-zA-Z ]*)");

var alpha = match.Groups["Alpha"].Value;
var num = match.Groups["Numeric"].Value;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex doesn't include any decimals. You'll want to do something like:

```
var numAlpha = new Regex(@"(?<Numeric>\d+(\.\d+)?) (?<Alpha>[a-zA-Z ]*)");
```

This changes the numeric portion to 1 or more digit followed by an optional decimal section. Note I also moved the trailing space for the numeric part out of the regex.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. I removed the space between Numeric and Alpha parenthesis so that I can have input as "25.27" or "25.27 " or "25.27 ft".